# Delphi TrackBar On Stop

Tags: delphi, media-player, trackbar

I am making a basic music player and am using a TTrackBar as the progress in the song.  As well I want to make it so u can drag the bar and fast forward the song.

Currently I have an OnChange event with the following line:

```
MediaPlayer1.position := TrackBar1.value... (with proper casting)
```

but what happens is that it skips the song along as I drag making a choppy sound as it plays the song at certain random points along the way.

What I really want is for when the user stops dragging the song should change.  What event is this?  The onStopDrop even doesn't do the trick..

Answer (score 2):

The scroll notification messages arrive though `WM_HSCROLL` or `WM_VSCROLL`, depending on the orientation of your track bar. These surface in the VCL control as `CN_HSCROLL` and `CN_VSCROLL`. You need to handle these messages and ignore message for which the scroll code is `TB_THUMBTRACK` to prevent the control to fire the `OnChange` event when the user drags the slider.

For example, here is an interposer control that does what you need:

```
type
  TTrackBar = class(Vcl.ComCtrls.TTrackBar)
  protected
    procedure CNHScroll(var Message: TWMHScroll); message CN_HSCROLL;
    procedure CNVScroll(var Message: TWMVScroll); message CN_VSCROLL;
  end;

implementation

procedure TTrackBar.CNHScroll(var Message: TWMHScroll);
begin
  if Message.ScrollCode = TB_THUMBTRACK then
    Message.Result := 0
  else
    inherited;
end;

procedure TTrackBar.CNVScroll(var Message: TWMVScroll);
begin
  if Message.ScrollCode = TB_THUMBTRACK then
    Message.Result := 0
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

Comment: With a horizontal trackbar, `TTrackBar.CNHScroll` is always being called exactly TWICE in `else inherited`.