# Resource Not Found for firemonkey app

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am building a firemonkey mobile application.

I have gone to projects -> Resources and Images.

Added "statusled.png" and the identifier is "LedOff" type "RCDATA"

In my form2.FormShow procedure I have this:

```
var
   offLed: TBitmap;

implementation

procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  jsonObj: TJSonObject;
  T: TResourceStream;

  litem: TListViewItem;
begin
  T := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'LedOff', 'RT_RCDATA');
  offLed.Create;
  offLed.LoadFromStream(T);
end;
```

When I run this and form2 opens I get "Resource LedOff not found" why is this?

Comment: I'm wondering what happened at this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073183/delphi-trackbar-on-stop) You asked, I gave an answer, and you gave no feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource type should not be quoted:

```
T := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'LedOff', RT_RCDATA);
```

---

Note that `offLed.Create` looks very dubious. I suspect that should read `offLed := TSomeClass.Create` where `TSomeClass` might be `TBitmap`, but only you can tell for sure.

Comment: Thanks, but now I am getting an Accessviolation.  Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Well, that's a different question altogether. But I've got an answer for that too. The second part of my answer explains that. I don't know what `TSomeClass` should be because I don't know what's in the resource, or what type `offLed` is. You presumably know that.

Comment: Also, I am storing a png as the resource and added some more detail to explain the second part of your response

Comment: So I guess it should read `offLed := TBitmap.Create`. Only you can know that. We can only guess at what `offLed` is. Remember that you asked about the resource stream error.